# Mysql, trigger auto add new record in table2, if new record in table 1 is added

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set MYSQL to trigger auto add new record in table 2 in the event that table 1 is added with new record?

for instance table 1 is added with new record column (username = "X", age = 25, gender="male"), table 2 will auto add a new record (username = "X", position="test")

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL auto insert a row into table2 on an insert to table1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919137/mysql-auto-insert-a-row-into-table2-on-an-insert-to-table1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use triggers for doing this, see the [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigg). But you have to consider certain factors before doing it, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919137/mysql-auto-insert-a-row-into-table2-on-an-insert-to-table1)